# When will two fields have same ramification index over $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field, ramification

My purpose is to decide whether two different field extensions $K_1, K_2$ of $\mathbb Q_p$ have same ramification index or not, provided $[K_1:\mathbb Q_p]=[K_2: \mathbb{Q}_p]$ and $K_2=\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[n]{-p})$ for some natural number $n$.

For example, consider two field extensions $K_1:=\mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt[9]{1})$ and $K_2:=\mathbb{Q}_3(\sqrt[6]{-3})$ over the $3$-adic field $\mathbb Q_3$.

Note that $K_1$ is cyclotomic field with degree of extension $\varphi(9)=6$ and it is totally ramified since $9=3^2$.

In other word, $K_1/\mathbb{Q}_p$ has ramification index $6$.

Now consider the field extension $K_2$. The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[6]{-3}$ is $x^6+3$, which is Eisenstein at prime $p=3$. So it is also totally ramified.

Therefore, the ramification index of $K_2/\mathbb Q_3$ is also $6$.

So I have mentioned two field extensions $K_1$ and $K_2$ of $\mathbb Q_3$ which are different but both has same degree of extension and same ramification index.

Certainly, the information that the degree of extensions of $K_1$ and $K_2$, being equal, was not enough for conclude their ramification index same.

So the question: Why $K_1$ and $K_2$ has same ramification index ? What made it possible here ? I mean, was there any general criterion of looking at the ramification index without doing calculations as I did here ?

More generally,

> how to decide whether two different fields extensions $K_1, K_2$ of $\mathbb Q_p$ have same ramification index or not ?

provided that we know $[K_1: \mathbb{Q}_p]=[K_2: \mathbb{Q}_p]$ and $K_2$ is always of the form $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt[n]{-p})$.

So what is the general criteria that their ramification inde will be same ? What might be the possible forms of the other field $K_1$ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since @PaulGarrett has given me the prompt, I’ll say something about higher ramification. This is a way of examining how close to each other the various roots $\lambda,\lambda'$ of the defining equation $f=0$ may be, when you choose $f$ so that one root $\lambda$ generates the ring of integers of the extension field $K$, $\mathcal O_K=\Bbb Z_p[\lambda]$. In the case of an unramified extension, as I recall, the differences between two roots will all be units. It’s the totally ramified extensions where higher ramification theory comes into its own.

Then let $\lambda$ be a uniformizing element of $\mathcal O_K$, $K$ totally ramified over $k$, with $v_k(\lambda)=1/e$ where $e$ is the ramification index (and the degree of the extension). We take $v_k$ normalized so that $v_k(k^\times)=\Bbb Z$. And let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial for $\lambda$, necessarily an Eisenstein polynomial over $\mathcal O_k$. Then put $g(x)=f(x+\lambda)$, whose roots are the quantities $\lambda'-\lambda$. We want a good way of measuring the size(s) of the roots of $g$.

Well, you measure the size of the roots of a polynomial with the Newton Polygon, but if you encode the same information in a kind of dual convex body that’s sometimes called the Newton Copolygon, you get something a little more useful. You can stretch this out horizontally by a factor of $e$ and consider the boundary to be the graph of a function, and thereby get the *Hassse-Herbrand Transition Function* $\psi^K_k$, which also has the wonderful property of being functorial: if $L\supset K\supset k$ is a chain of totally ramified extensions, then $\psi^L_k=\psi^K_k\circ\psi^L_K$.

Note that there are no Galois groups in this story. We can apply it to the two extensions mentioned at the beginning, $\Bbb Q_3(\zeta_9)$ and $\Bbb Q_3((-3)^{1/6})$. The two uniformizers are, respectively, $\tau=\zeta_9-1$ and $\pi=(-3)^{1/6}$. The minimal polynomial for $\zeta_9$ is $\frac{x^9-1}{x^3-1}$, so the minimal polynomial for $\tau$ is $f_1(x)=\frac{(x+1)^9-1}{(x+1)^3-1}$. The numerator and denominator have no constant, while the first-degree coefficient upstairs is $9$, downstairs is $3$, thus the quotient, known to be a polynomial, has constant coefficient $9/3=3$. Looking at the quotient modulo $3$, you see that there, the quotient is $x^6$. Thus $f_1$ is Eisenstein, which we already knew, didn’t we?
Forming $g_1(x)=f_1(x+\tau)$, as above, we need to look closely at $g_1$ and its Newton Polygon (and Copolygon). It’s somewhat of a pain to do the computation this way, but you find that the $v_p$-value of the first coefficient is $3/2$, the value of the third is $1/2$ and of the sixth is zero. This gives vertices of the Polygon at $(1,3/2)$, $(3,1/2)$, and $(6,0)$. The Copolygon (in the Cartesian $(\xi,\eta)$-plane) is described by the corresponding inequalities $\eta\le\xi+3/2$, $\eta\le3\xi+1/2$, and $\eta\le6\xi$. The vertices are where two half-planes’ boundaries intersect, namely at $(1/6,1)$ and $(1/2,2)$. Stretch by a factor of six to get the points $(1,1)$ and $(3,2)$ (the “breaks” in traditional terminology), exactly what you’ll find in Serre’s *Corps Locaux*, except that my coordinatization of the Cartesian plane is off from Serre’s by one in each direction.

If you do the corresponding computation for $\sqrt[6]{-3}$, you’ll see that it’s much less messy, giving $g_2(x)=(x+\pi)^6+3$ with the Polygon’s vertices at $(1,11/6)$, $(3,1/2)$ and $(6,0)$. The Copolygon is defined by the corresponding inequalities $\eta\le\xi+11/6$, $\eta\le3\xi+1/2$, and $\eta\le6\xi$. Here, the half-planes’ boundaries intersect at $(1/6,1)$
and $(2/3,5/2)$. Stretching by six gives the vertices of the polygonal Hasse-Herbrand function at $(1,1)$ and $(4,5/2)$. Here, the “breaks” are *not* at integer points, which is fine, because the Galois group of the normal closure of our field is not abelian.

Comment: Thank you Professor @Lubin

Comment: Great! Very illuminating! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

For abelian (Galois) extensions, understanding ramification is part of "local classfield theory". As a special case of that local classfield theory, the *cyclic* degree $n$ extensions $k$ are in natural bijection with the subgroups of index $n$ of $\mathbb Q^\times_p$, with Galois group isomorphic to the cyclic quotients $\mathbb Q_p^\times/N_{k/\mathbb Q^\times_p}(k^\times)$. In that case, the ramification degree is the index of the norms from the units of the bigger field in the units $\mathbb Z_p^\times$. So, in that special case, if we can "understand" the finite-index subgroups of $\mathbb Z_p^\times$ with cyclic quotient, we "understand" the ramifications of cyclic extensions.

Of course, the ground field doesn't have to be $\mathbb Q_p$, and abelian extensions are treatable as part of classfield theory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does the isomorphism between the fields $K_1$ and $K_2$ preserve the ramification filtrations of their corresponding Galois groups ? In simple word, is ramification degree an invariant under isomorphism of fields ? I think it is not true as in my example, the two fields are not isomorphic but their ramification index is same. So the opposite question is-if two fields  are isomorphic, can their ramification index be unequal ?

Comment: Ramification degree _is_ an isomorphism invariant of local field extensions ... Your example is sort of a contrapositive, that two not-isomorphic field extensions of a common base field ($\mathbb Q_p$) have the same ramification _index_. Further, the ramification filtrations (upper and lower indices?) are preserved under isomorphism, since they, too, are instrinsically defined.

Comment: thank you very much. Anyway, in the 3rd line of your answer, is it $\mathbb Q^p$ or  $\mathbb Q_p$ ?

Comment: Oop, typo, let me repair it. :)

Comment: do you have any working example in mind or helpful reference ?

Comment: Your quotient groups should involve $\mathbf Q_p$, not $\mathbf Q$.

Comment: @KCd, oops, thanks. :)

Comment: The ramification filtrations of those two extensions are different. The *really* interesting conundrum is to distinguish between two extensions with the same (for instance) Hasse-Herbrand transition function.

Comment: Some of the audience here would be quite interested to hear more from Professor @lubin about further details and examples! :)  I myself am just an amateur at algebraic number theory, an "end user"... :)